# Почему нельзя обратиться напрямую к элементам чьи ID уже присвоены?

Tags: java, android-studio

Начал изучение Android Studio и Java после c#, js, php. В ходе изучения я каждый раз недоумевал почему так всё сложно в работе с создаваемыми на layout элементами? Что происходит с переменными? В чем сила такого подхода?

Вот к примеру, для того, чтобы получить текст содержащийся в EditText необходимо сделать следующую операцию:

```
EditText userField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userFiledEditText);
String s = userField.getText();
```

Это ужасно! И даже, если после шарпа не обращать внимание на отсутствие var и то, что нельзя обратиться напрямую к элементам чьи ID уже присвоены (напоминает js), ТО какого .. лешего нельзя сразу работать с полученным результатом функции?!?! What?! Или я чего-то не знаю?

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.id.userFiledEditText).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Уважаемые, кто в состоянии корректно мне объяснить этот факт? Я верю, что все это сделано ради чего-то благого и несет в себе смысл, но хочется понять.

ЗЫ: без холивара и пинков от гуру джавистов.

Comment: Так надо. И по другому не будет, вы можете смириться или уйти. Так же не понятно, что вы хотите увидеть в ответе: чтобы переделали, как хотите вы, чтобы вам разрешили делать по другому, чтобы вас утешили великим замыслом .. или к чему этот поток эмоцианального недоумевания? Данный вопрос абсолютно неформат на данном ресурсе, где решают практические проблемы, а не утешают мигрантов с других платформ.

Comment: String s = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.userFiledEditText)).userField.getText();

Comment: Можно воспользоваться ButterKnife. Тогда можно будет делать биндинги на аннотациях, например, так `@BindView(R.id.userFiledEditText) EditText userField;`

Answer (score 1):

За всей этой эмоцианальной шелухой я, кажется понял, в чем проблема.

Разметка написана на декларируемом языке XML, она не содержит объектов-виджетов с которыми можно было бы проводить манипуляции из кода. Для преобразования в объекты разметка должна предварительно пройти инфлейт (парсинг преобразования из XML в объекты)

Идентификатор типа R.id.name - целое число типа int.  При парсинге разметки создается служебный класс R, который связвает имена виджетов с числовыми значениями (ID). Далее по этим ID можно извлечь объект, который помечен этим ID из массива объектов View, которые были созданы при парсинге разметки.

Для того, чтобы  использовать методы, применимые к View, должен быть объект этого типа, которым число, очевидно, не является.

Методом findViewById() вы получаете объект, к которому прикреплен определенный идентификатор. Далее вы уже работаете с объектом, для которого можно вызывать методы.

PS: уберите из вопроса весь этот "ужас" "как же так" и прочие эмоции, эти восклиццания десь не уместны.